# Trouble with HTML Canvas Drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to do this pixel drawing in HTML5 canvas, and can't figure out what's causing this behavior.

I have it set up so that the pixel "block" is 32*32 (I only have the character now, but the background tiles and other characters are the exact same size), so the window should be a grid divisible by 32.

I have a JS function to offset the X and Y of the character, but I seem to be keeping the offset, even though  (I think) it shouldn't be changing it globally, only locally.

Thus, I can't do a simple grid of 4x4. Calling them in this order: 0,0; 0,1; 1,0; 1,1 should show a grid like this:

```
xx
xx
```

Instead it does this:

```
x 
xx 
  x
```

Here's a JSFiddle page: http://jsfiddle.net/pzwu38cq/

The calls that draw the pixels are in the JS panel, at the very bottom

I'm probably just missing something really simple, but I appreciate help in this.

Comment: Scott Doxey & treeno both correctly answer that your glitch is with "+=". BTW, When I read your question I assumed you wanted to do alpha blending of your warriors, but all your pixels are either on (alpha=255) or off (0). Since this is the case...why not use 32x32 images instead of pixel manipulation?

Comment: @markE I am working from another game that uses images, I wanted to remake it using this method of canvas pixel drawing instead (or CSS pixel drawing, but I read this was faster). However the purpose of repeating this isn't to do blending, it's to have a map with background tiles (I just only have the character in my code currently)

Comment: Fair enough! If speed is important in your design, you might want to check out compositing, and in particular `context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over'`.  This compositing mode allows you draw your warriors first and then draw your background last *under the already drawn warriors*. If just offer this because pixel manipulation is slower compared to compositing. Good luck with your project! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are  always changing the same Array by

```
pixels[i][0] += offsetX * 32;
pixels[i][1] += offsetY * 32;
```

Try to make a deep-copy in drawPixels() like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/pzwu38cq/11/

I also changed

```
drawPixels(warrior, 0,0);
drawPixels(warrior, 0,1);
drawPixels(warrior, 1,0);
drawPixels(warrior, 1,1);
```

slightly because the indeces where redundant, looks like a C&P-thing :-)

Comment: Thanks, I made the 1,1 on all because it looked easier to see the problem (that it kept adding 32 to each new one). See the question for the grid like you changed, and the original result.

Comment: Ah, ok I didn't see that, but makes sense

Comment: By the way: If your getting in performance-trouble because of the deepcopy, you could also try to pass the offsets to drawPixel(pixels, offsetX, offsetY). Then you dont need to change the array at all.

Answer (score 2):

This block of code was updating the original array (warrior):

```
pixels[i][0] += offsetX * 32;
pixels[i][1] += offsetY * 32;
```

Switching it to using a temporary array will achieve your desired results.

```
drawPixel([
    pixels[i][0] + offsetX * 32,
    pixels[i][1] + offsetY * 32,
    pixels[i][2],
    pixels[i][3],
    pixels[i][4],
    pixels[i][5]
]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pzwu38cq/12/